# How to validate JSF errors on XHTML pages with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, intellij-idea

i just installed IntelliJ and created a web project with JSF.
I created a xhtml page and a managed bean. In my managed bean i have a method:

```
public void doSomething(int x){}
```

Then, in my xhtml:

```
<h:commandButton value="Do it!" action="#{myManagedBean.doSomething()}"/>
```

As you noticed, my method requires an integer parameter, but when i called it i passed no parameters. It should show an error on this line but it does not.
It only shows an error if i do a "Ctrl+Click" above the doSomething() statement. But it does not highlight the error or anything like that.

How can i change it do behave like eclipse or netbeans, where it shows a big error on the file name and on the line where the error happened?

Answer (score 0):

Intellij highlight errors in expression language. but Intellij Idea 13 JSF support is not very stable yet. you can see some problems with highlights in JSF pages.